# Android Notifications Listening in the Background

Tags: android, notifications

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html on how to create notifications for android. Now my question is: **How do I go about listening in the background for updates in the application?**

Say I have an app that lets users invite other users to events. I want the invited user to get a notification when this happens. Where would I listen for this in the application? Should I be making a call to the database every few minutes? Is this even possible to do when the application is running in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to create a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in your app. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) specifically for using an IntentService.